# Can I view close reasons before the question is closed?

Tags: support, vote-to-close

I asked [this question](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/51444/how-do-i-protect-my-shop-from-teleporters#51445) this morning. Despite having a relatively active discussion with some good answers, it has received a few close votes. No comment was left regarding the close votes [as we recommend](https://worldbuilding.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3773/reminder-to-close-voters), so I am at a loss. Is there a way for me to view the close reasons prior to the event actually being closed? I would like to improve the question if possible, but I can't do that if I don't know what people find close-worthy.

Comment: Oh, sorry, one of those was me. I voted for too broad. That's what all of them are for, by the way. I was hoping someone would see my VTC, and either disagree or agree and have better luck thinking of what to put in a comment.

Comment: @DaaaahWhoosh No worries. I am more curious if this functionality exists. It would alleviate the confusion about closed votes with no comments.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

According to the Help Center, users are supposed to be able to "[view and cast close and reopen votes on your own questions](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/view-close-votes)." after 250 reputation.  I see you are well past that, so I'm not sure why it hasn't worked for you.  The counts appear after clicking the "close" link under the question.

Comment: Ah so it is. I had avoided this button thinking it was to cast a close vote on my own question, something I had blundered into in the past.

Comment: @Kys- Right! After reading, either press your keyboard 'esc' key or click the black 'x' link in the corner of the vote dialog.

Comment: @Kys Voting to close only happens once you explicitly click to vote to close. (The only exception to this, for some reason that escapes me, is review queue audits. That, however, doesn't apply here. Compare [In the review queue, audits should only fail (or pass) you once you actually would take action](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/212122/157730).) The vote to close dialog works exactly the same way as the flag dialog, but has slightly different options to choose from.